# Js file not found

Tags: javascript

I am getting a random error when I attempt to link a javascript file to my web page. I am fairly new to javascript. I looked back to my notes but yet I still get the error.

Here is the Html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <style>
        table{
            margin:auto;
            width:100%;
        }
        
        tr.spacer{
            height:55px;
        }
    
        div#header{
            width: 100%;
            text-align: right;
        }
        
        div#wrapper{
            /*border: solid red 1px;*/
            width: 750px;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
        }
        
        div.dealer,div.player{
            float:left;
            background-image:url("cards.png");
            width:74px;
            height:99px;
            /* move 1 card right is -73px */
            /* move 1 card down is -98px */
            background-position:0px 0px ;
            
            margin-left:15px;
            margin-right:15px;
        }
        img{
            width:214px;
            height:196px;
        }

        input[type='button']{
            width: 201px;
            height:75px;
            background-color : #4CAF50;
            text-align:center;
            margin: 25px;
        }
        
        input#reload{
            margin: 7px 35px;
            
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="deal();">
    <div id="header">
        <input id="reload" type = "button" value="Start a new Game" onclick="location.reload();">
    </div>
    
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table border=0 id="blackjacktable">
            <tr class="spacer"></tr>

            <tr>
                <th id="dealerLabel" colspan=2 >Dealer  </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2 id="dealerScore"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="dealerHand">
                    <img id="dealer1" src="" width="107" height="98">
                    <img id="dealer2" src="" width="107" height="98">
                </td>

            </tr>
            
            <tr class="spacer"></tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th id="playerLabel" colspan=2>Player   </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2 id="playerScore"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="btnDraw" type="button" onclick="requestPlayerCard();" value="Draw 1 more Card">
                    <input id="btnHold" type="button" onclick="completeDealerHand();" value="Hold">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="playerHand">
                    <img id="player1" src="" width="107" height="98">
                    <img id="player2" src="" width="107" height="98">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript file:

```
var cardsArr = new Array(
                'img/1.png','img/2.png','img/3.png','img/4.png','img/5.png','img/6.png','img/7.png','img/8.png',
                'img/9.png','img/10.png','img/11.png','img/12.png','img/13.png','img/14.png','img/15.png','img/16.png',
                'img/17.png','img/18.png','img/19.png','img/20.png','img/21.png','img/22.png','img/23.png','img/24.png',
                'img/25.png','img/26.png','img/27.png','img/28.png','img/29.png','img/30.png','img/31.png','img/32.png',
                'img/33.png','img/34.png','img/35.png','img/36.png','img/37.png','img/38.png','img/39.png','img/40.png',
                'img/41.png','img/42.png','img/43.png','img/44.png','img/45.png','img/46.png','img/47.png','img/48.png',
                'img/49.png','img/50.png','img/51.png','img/52.png');

function deal() {
    getRandCard();
}

function requestPlayerCard() {

}

function completeDealerHand() {

}

function getRandCard() {
    var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardsArr.length) + 1;
    document.getElementById("dealer1").src = [randomCard];
    document.getElementById("dealer2").src = 'img/back.png';
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
1:1 GET file:///C:/Users/Theod/Desktop/school/Internet%20programming/Assigments/Assignment%204/blackjack-students/blackjack/1 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I am fairly certain I am pathing to the right folder, I double checked it. I am using Notepadd++ for this assignment that I am doing.

Any suggestions?

one more thing, this is my folder structure: *C:\Users\Theod\Desktop\school\Internet programming\Assigments\Assignment 4\blackjack-students\blackjack\img*

Thanks

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing your folder structure.

Comment: I added it @Spectric.

Answer (score 0):

With function getRandCard you are sending as src only the number and not the extension. Try adding the .png

```
document.getElementById("dealer1").src = "" + [randomCard] + ".png";
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error :/

Comment: There is a problem with the naming of the files when the src goes looking for the image. try:  document.getElementById("dealer1").src = "img/" + [randomCard] + ".png";  If no luck just remove the img from all images and place them with the number only + the .png

Comment: That was the issue, thanks alot for your time :)

Comment: Good! welcome!!